# Create Azure Load Balancer for existing VMs in Azure Preview Portal

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I wouldn't generally ask such questions on SO but my patience has run out as I have lost a day on this. Does anyone know how on earth someone can create a simple Load Balancer to load balance two existing VMs. The VMs are Rabbit MQs and I need to put a load balancer in front to distribute the traffic accordingly.

I wish I could give bounty to anyone that helps out.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly share the error log.

Answer (score 2):

In your resource group, click + New to add a new resource and then search for "Load Balancer".

I have just tested, it seems to work :

[image: azure load balancer]

Once created, you can configure it to create your load balancing rules (and target your VMs).

Hope this helps,

Julien

Comment: Hey - I have been that far but I got stuck in "Once created, you can configure it to create your load balancing rules (and target your VMs)."

Comment: In other words - it doesnt let you target your VMs unless those are classic VMs and are created on Availability Groups. I dont think there is any way to assign a new (not classic) VM in an availability group.

Comment: are you using classic deployment for your VM or Azure Resource Manager ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: Resource Manager. Basically IF my VMs were on Availability groups I know how to progress and set the LB up (or I can see how to progress). But when you create a VM in Azure Preview Portal there is no way (that I can see) to add it to an availability group.

Comment: Ok I see. In fact, with ARM, you need to create a backend pool in the load balancer settings. Then you can add either an availability set or a single VM in the backend pool (maybe this will help to understand: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-arm/)

Comment: I m afraid this doesn't help. I still need to setup an availability group to add a VM to the backend pool.